# How to Format or Pad String date with zeros?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have date values that are formatted like this: `1/1/2015`.
These are produced by a Web Service which I cannot change:

How do I Format this: `1/1/2015` to `01/01/2015`, with the leading zero?

Tried this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:[##/##/####]}", "1/1/2015"));
```

And this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", "1/1/2015"));
```

But I get the same formatted output.

Comment: `"1/1/2015"` is a `string`, not a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have date values that are formatted like this

In .NET, a [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) does not have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. *Textual* representation (aka string representation) of a `DateTime` can have a format.

If you have string like that, parse it to `Datetime` and get it's string representation with `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

```
string s = "1/1/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump(); // 01/01/2015
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am assuming there is no way to format the values without using `TryParseExact`?

Comment: `TryParseExact` does not affect format. The format passed in is the current form of the string being parsed. Once you have a `DateTime` object you can format it using overloads of `ToString`

Comment: @UnaverageGuy `TryParseExact` does not format _anything_. It parses your `string` to `DateTime` with specific format and culture settings.You can use `ParseExact` method as well. You can even use some string methods to split your string with `/` and add your first and second item `0` as leading. But that would be ugly (or not the best way) because your string is perfect candidate to parsing a `DateTime`. The `dd` and `MM` format specifiers get your days and months numbers with leading zeros. `ToString` method get's formatted string representation of your `DateTime` with specific culture.

Comment: @UnaverageGuy - you could split the `string` by the date dividers, check the length of each part and prepend a zero if it's less than two. But honestly, why *wouldn't* you want to work with an appropriate data type (`DateTime`) as soon as possible?

Comment: @Corak: Good point, I was just looking for alternatives so that I can understand and make better decision as to how I can handle this: I was looking at `Format.String()` because I am already getting the Data as a `String.` But you make a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
return yourDateTimeValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

**Edit:**

Since you are storing your date as string then try like this:

```
string s = "1/1/2015";
DateTime dt = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the date string into `DateTime` then get it as `MM/dd/yyyy` or whatever format you want.

```
DateTime.Parse("1/1/2015").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: Be careful. Your `MM/dd/yyyy` format _might_ not generate the same output without supply any `IFormatProvider`.